# When is a short/resistor appropriate for muting typical stereo audio and microphones?

Tags: audio

I have been looking at different methods for muting audio from a generic 3.5mm jack and noticed that depending on what is being muted there are some situations where directly shorting the signal is recommended, and some where resistors of varying values with or without an accompanying capacitor are used.

Ex: per [this article](https://sound-au.com/articles/muting.html#s2) I found the mention of an inline resistor that appears to limit current from an otherwise shorted input in a mute circuit:

[image: Relay-Based Mute Circuit]

> There are some circuits that may not be happy with a shorted output - discrete opamps and other all transistor circuits. Project 37 (DoZ Preamp) is one example, but provided the 100 ohm
> output resistor is included it's unlikely that it will come to any
> harm with normal signal levels (up to 3V RMS output).  The easy way to
> ensure that it's happy at any level is to increase the output resistor
> to 560Ω.  This is quite low enough for any preamp, and means that a
> shorted output cannot damage the preamp.

This implies that a good practice *could* be to just throw a 560Ω resistor inline to prevent an actual short, since this would protect various transistor circuits.

- Is this always a good practice?

In [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196291/understanding-audio-output-and-resistor) about the presence of resistors on the outputs of amps, filters, etc. the answers mention that inline resistors can be important for impedance matching, and standardization. Also that:

> For a pair of headphones (or speakers in general), you want the output impedance as low as possible to make the cone follow the drive voltage as close as possible.

- If a resistor is added inline for current limiting (like R1 in the diagram above) could such a value be large enough to affect the impedance matching / cone driving? Some of the diagrams show values up to ~10K. Is there a practical limit?

Additionally:

- Is there anything wrong with shorting just the **input** to a speaker, or other audio device (disconnected from a signal source)?
- I've read some varying opinions on whether a microphone can be shorted to ground. Wouldn't shorting cause issues with the DC offset that powers the microphone?

Comment: Re, "...shorting just the input to a speaker..." The input to a speaker is the _output_ from an amplifier. You probably don't want to short the output from an amplifier.

Comment: better question: if they're going to use a relay anyway, why not use the relay to just disconnect the microphone wire??

Comment: @SolomonSlow right, but what about "(disconnected from a signal source)". And what about other devices that have inputs, like an amplifier?

Comment: I have never heard of any situation in which there would be any benefit to muting a loudspeaker that is not connected to any power source. Furthermore, you would not want to put a _switch_ on a speaker to short it out because if somebody accidentally closed the switch while the speaker _was_ connected to an amp, that potentially could damage the amp.

Comment: @user253751, microphone preamps expect signal levels as low as a few hundred microvolts. A floating microphone input can pick up electrical noise that a shorted input would not. (I've got a mixer on my desk right beside my computer, and when I crank up the gain on an un-used input, I can hear both white noise, and an AC hum.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Good point, but I have a situation where the speakers automatically shut off after a while with no signal. In the mean-time they will buzz if the signal cable has been disconnected from the source end (it's a hassle to get to the power switches). It's a bit specific, but demonstrates a circumstance where an input could need muting.

Comment: If there is any DC in the signal that you are shorting then there will be a POP sound when muting and when unmuting. If there is audio happening when you mute or unmute then there will be a POP. Therefore, slowly attenuate the signal before muting the signal and unmute before slowly allowing the signal level.

Comment: @SolomonSlow well they've also drawn a SPDT relay so it's perfectly capable of shorting the input when turned off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't shorting cause issues with the DC offset that powers the microphone?

If you're talking about [*phantom power*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_power) which can be supplied by most pro-audio mixing consoles, the phantom power does not bias the microphone element. Professional microphones are connected to the mixer via three pins and a shield. Two of the three pins form a differential pair, and the third pin is ground. Phantom power is applied between the differential pair and ground. If you want to mute the input, you can short the differential pair, *without* shorting it to ground.

If you're talking about a D.C. bias on a 3.5mm microphone jack, then *hopefully,* it's current limited, and the mic power supply will be designed to indefinitely withstand a dead short. The same usually is true of phantom power supplied by a mixing console, probably with the added complication that shorting any one mic input should not prevent it from supplying power to other microphones.

Comment: Thanks, this and the comments have clarified muting microphones a lot. Can you provide any guidance on muting other components? (Maybe it should be a separate question for clarity?)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Interesting question.
Professional microphones generally are shorted. The system is normally a 600 Ohm circuit. There is a differential pair from the microphone element and a third wire for phantom power if needed. This differential pair eliminates a lot of noise and hum by putting it into common mode. Phantom power is supplied separately to each microphone via a resistor. My system has if my memory is correct 6.8K resistors. This shorts the sound (600 Ohm) circuit, not the power. Hobby and toy microphones I need a schematic to be sure.

Simple rule if the wires are connected to a speaker do not short them you could possibly blow your amp.